# Is the using var always executed?

Tags: c#, using

In some code that I maintain, I came across this:

```
int Flag;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), true))
{
    Flag = 1;
    // Some computing code
}

if(Flag == 1)
{
    // Some other code
}
```

Which, from what I understand, is a way to do some other instruction if the `using` part was executed. But is there a possibility for `using` to be not executed (Except if an exception is raised)? Or is this completely useless code?

Comment: May I suggest reading [using Statement (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)?

Comment: using is always executed. It's used for RAII. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Comment: The code you've written wouldn't even compile - `Flag` isn't definitely assigned.

Comment: @IInspectable I did, but I didn't found and answer to my question, maybe I didn't catch the whole sens since I'm not a native english speaker

Comment: Yes it's useless, `Flag` must be assigned before the `if` otherwise the compiler would reject it.

Comment: @JonSkeet it does compile, at least in the program I maintain

Comment: @JonSkeet it should be able to compile due to that it's still set in an executable scope.

Comment: @Bauss: Doh, you're absolutely right. My bad.

Comment: I checked it, it compiles. Obviously because `using` is allways executed compiler assumes that `Flag` is definitly set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is useless...

If you add a `try`... `catch` it could have a sense... You want to know if/where an exception happens, like:

```
int flag = 0;

try
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), true))
    {
        flag = 1;

        reader.ReadToEnd();
        flag = 2;
    }

    flag = int.MaxValue;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}

if (flag == 0)
{
    // Exception on opening
}
else if (flag == 1)
{
    // Exception on reading
}
else if (flag == 2)
{
    // Exception on closing
}
else if (flag == int.MaxValue)
{
    // Everything OK
}
```

Comment: Nice example!     `flag = 3;` means here "Everything went well" right?

Comment: @Thomas Yep... as you said.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [using Statement documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), you can translate your code to

```
int flag;
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), true);
    try
    {
        flag = 1;
        // Some computing code
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null) ((IDisposable)reader).Dispose();
    }
}

if (flag == 1)
{
    // Some other code
}
```

If you reach the `flag == 1` test, that means your code didn't thrown and therefor, flag was set to `1`. So, yes, `flag` stuffs are completely useless code in your case.

Comment: No, it isn't useless. It executes `IDisposable::Close` when leaving the following scope.

Comment: @IInspectable, the OP talks about the utility of the `Flag`variable, so do I.

Comment: This answer is correct. If the line of code `if(Flag == 1)` is reached, `Flag` can only be 1. The only way it could not be 1 is if an exception was thrown before it was set to 1, in which case that line of code will not be reached.

Answer (score 0):

The code is always executed within the using statement unless the creation of the instance throws an exception.

Take this into account.

```
int Flag;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), true))
{
    // This scope is executed if the StreamReader instance was created
    // If ex. it can't open the file etc. then the scope is not executed
    Flag = 1;
}

// Does not run any code past this comment
// if the using statement was not successfully executed
// or there was an exception thrown within the using scope

if(Flag == 1)
{
    // Some other code
}
```

However there is a way that you could make sure the next part of the code is executed.
Using a try statement would give you the possibility to make sure the flag is set.
This may not be what you want to do, but based on your code it would make sure the flag is set. Perhaps you need some other kind of logic.

```
int Flag;
try
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), true))
    {
        // This scope is executed if the StreamReader instance was created
        // If ex. it can't open the file etc. then the scope is not executed
        Flag = 1;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Do stuff with the exception
    Flag = -1; // Error Flag perhaps ??
}

// Any code after this is still executed

if(Flag == 1)
{
    // Some other code
}
```